# How to determine when jQuery.ScrollTo has finished smooth scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I'm using [Ariel Flesler's awesome scrollto plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).  But I want to determine when the plugin has finished scrolling. The scrollto speed is set to 800 on my page.  How can I do that?

I've tried:

```
        isScrolling = true;
        jQuery(listWrapper).scrollTo(theId, 800);
        isScrolling = false;
```

But it seems as though `isScrolling = false` gets set before the scrolling completes.

I have some JavaScript attached to the scrollto event in addition to this.  The scrolling slows down to a painful speed because it's trying to do smooth scroll and run the scroll event at the same time.  I was hoping to effectively disable the scroll event while it's scrolling, and re-enable it when the scrolling has completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin has a callback function that is called when the animation is over:

```
onAfter: A function to be called after the whole animation ended.
```

Comment: I  didn't see that in the documentation haha.  thanks!  @Sorin S.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onAfter` event which is triggered after the scrolling has finished which is also the third argument of `scrollTo` plugin as a callback function. Try this.

```
    isScrolling = true;
    jQuery(listWrapper).scrollTo(theId, 800, function(){
        isScrolling = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), there's an `onAfter` option that takes a function to execute once the scrolling has completed.